# Scroll a div to the center of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is a model of my div structure.

```
<div id="fruitWrapper">
  <div id="lychee">LYCHEE</div> //info div 1
  <div id="mango">MANGO</div> //info div 2
  <div id="apple">APPLE</div> //info div 3
  <div id="papaya">PAPAYA</div> //info div 4
  <div id="pineapple">PINEAPPLE</div> //info div 5
</div>
```

I've got about 75 `info divs` nested inside `#fruitWrapper`. All `info divs` are equal in height. I have limited the height of `#fruitWrapper` to 1½ times as the height of a single `info div` (width is 100% to page width).

```
.info_div{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I've got 75 icons on the page. How can I make a particular `info div` to scroll to the center of `#fruitWrapper`?

```
showInfo(papaya);
function showInfo(fruit) {
      $('#fruitWrapper').scrollTop($('#fruitWrapper').scrollTop() + $('#'+fruit).position().top - $('#fruitWrapper').height()/2 + $('#'+fruit).height()/2);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0vp7gwe3/

```
showInfo('papaya');

function showInfo(fruit) {
    console.log($('#' + fruit));
    $('#fruitWrapper').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#" + fruit).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's close. I 'm looking to center it vertically. #up-vote :)